# Broken Font Size in Chrome on Windows 8.1

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, windows-8.1, dpi

Since updating my PC to Windows 8.1, I have been experiencing an issue with font size on several websites that I have designed when displayed on Chrome.

Nothing has changed with the design of the sites.

My navigation is breaking because the text is now too long for the menu bar. Having done a few searches, I found an answer on the superuser forum relating to HiDPI.

https://superuser.com/questions/803601/text-size-suddenly-got-bigger-on-all-sites-on-google-chrome

The answers posted to this question relate to solving the problem on users' local machines. I'm unsure if this occurs on all machines running Windows 8.1 viewing in Chrome. If the problem is a bug, how do I resolve it?

Here is a JSFiddle which is still showing a broken display on my screen.

`no code to accompany this`[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/du74m40L/1/)

(Please remember that this may display correctly if you do not experience the bug. If the bug exists, the last menu item will appear below the first)

Should I decrease the size of my menu fonts, and affect the design of the site, to guarantee the menu functioning correctly?

I need a fix for everyone experiencing this problem, not just me.

Does anyone know of a fix?

Comment: It's only problem with your computer. If you fix that error than there is no need to modify website.

Comment: I understand that, but unfortunately there will be other users with the same problem, and they wont be searching superuser for a solution. So to them, my site is broken. Fixing it for them will affect quality for others without the bug. I need to find a solution relating to font rendering settings or the like.

Comment: It's not related with your website. If user don't have monitor, will you try to fix that too?

Comment: Yes, I know that, but if there is a bug with 'System A', which does a similar thing to 'System B', I'd like to start using 'System B' as everyone will benefit. 'System B' would give everyone without the monitor you talk about, another monitor.

Answer (score 0):

Your best option would be to make sure that the viewport is set to the default of 0 and that the core font-size is set for all elements.

**Viewport**

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

> The width property controls the size of the viewport. It can be set to a specific number of pixels like `width=600` or to the special value `device-width` value which is the width of the screen in CSS pixels at a scale of 100%. (There are corresponding height and device-height values, which may be useful for pages with elements that change size or position based on the viewport height.)
>
> The `initial-scale` property controls the zoom level when the page is first loaded. The `maximum-scale`, `minimum-scale`, and `user-scalable`properties control how users are allowed to zoom the page in or out.

[Viewport MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag)

**Font**

```
* {
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

This will set the `font-size` to 16px across all of the elements and will override whatever the user's browser default font-size is.

Both of these used together should help in some way to making sure that all browsers and device types render your page as expected.

Comment: Thanks for the answer you have given. I think you could be on to a solution as it only affects certain elements on the page. I have added a JSFiddle to the question, to show the problem.

Comment: Sadly, I'm on a mac and can't currently recreate the issue you have above. I was more going on previous experience with different font rendering dependant on browser. If this issue persists even with the above solutions, then it may simply be an issue with the CSS renderer within Chrome which is something that no one can fix within CSS.

Comment: it is strange that it only happens on some sites. As it's an older site, I think perhaps my css discipline may be what is letting me down.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a mediaquery that detects pixel density and change the font-size for this dpi, with this, users that hasn't the bug were not affected.